# How do I make a search bar and search button on the nav stay on that line when the window is shrunk?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I want the search bar and its search button to stay in one line when I make the window smaller from the right. When I make it smaller now, the search bar drops to another line, and the search button falls even further down.

Here is the HTML I have:

```html
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/""><img src="logo.png"></a>
      <div class="input-group">
         <form id="search-form" class='form-horizontal' onsubmit="goSearch()" id="searchInputHere">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search here."/>
            <button class="btn search-button form-control" type="submit" style="width:auto; float: right;"><i>BUTTON</i></button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </ul>
```

I want these always to be on the same, top line of the screen when the window is smaller.

Comment: Your code snippet is pretty much worthless without the CSS you are using.

Comment: Yes, please include your CSS as this is most likely what is causing the issue